# Relative path in configuration file

Tags: windows, winforms, relative-path

I created a shortcut to my application:
'C:\Program Files\Tools\Dir\Exe\Starting.exe'

My structure is like this:
Tools->Dir->Exe 
Tools->Dir->Applications

In Exe folder I have a config file that should start an app from Applications folder.

I tried this in configuration file:
'.\Applications\MyFirstApp\MyFirstApp.exe', but its not working.

I need a relative path that is working for:
'C:\Program Files\Tools\Dir\Applications\MyFirstApp\MyFirstApp.exe'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have the answer. The correct code to jump back to another folder is :

```
..\Applications\MyFirstApp\MyFirstApp.exe
```